# Is this the way to show this set is countable?

Tags: analysis, functions

This is a problem from an introductory analysis course I am taking,

Given a set $A=\{a+b\sqrt2:a,b\in\Bbb Q\}$. Show it is countable.

Note: I've seen similar questions on MSE (like for $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Z$ but not for $\Bbb Q$ )

Here is what I think I need to do:

(1) Find an injective function $f:A→\Bbb Q \times \Bbb Q$

(2) Find an injective function $g:\Bbb Q \times \Bbb Q→A$

(3) Use the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem and it is done.

For (1), I constructed a function $f(n) = n-b\sqrt2⇒f(a+b\sqrt2) = a+b\sqrt2-b\sqrt2 = (a,0)$

For (2), I'm not entirely sure how to show a ordered pair of rationals go to the the set A.

Is this in the right direction?

Comment: You can show $a + b\sqrt{2} = 0$ iff $a = b = 0$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$, and thus pass $(a, b) \to a + b \sqrt{2}$. Your first function is not injective though, for $a + \sqrt{2}$ and $a$ are mapped to the same pair $(a, 0)$. Note that the first observation hints a direct way to show a bijection exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to appeal to Schroder-Bernstein theorem. First of all, $f: A \to \mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$ given by $f(a+b\sqrt 2)= (a, b)$ is an injection. Now, observe that $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$ is countable. Using the previous two facts, you can find an injection from $A$ to $\mathbb N$. Now $A$ is equipotent with a subset of $\mathbb N$ and since every subset of $\mathbb N$ is countable, we have $A$ is countable.

Comment: After showing there is an injection between A and $\Bbb Q \times \Bbb Q$, can I say, 

Since, we know $\Bbb Q \times \Bbb Q$ is countable and there exists a injection between A and $\Bbb Q \times \Bbb Q$ it implies, 

$card(A) \le card(\Bbb Q \times \Bbb Q) = \aleph_0$

Comment: @JohnMacPherson It's okay but you would need to prove that for any set $A$, if $\text{card} A \le \aleph _{0}$ then $A$ is countable.